# iterate over files in pyspark from hdfs directory

Tags: pyspark

I have list of files in hdfs directory and I would like to iterate over files in pyspark from hdfs directory and store each file in a variable and use that variable for further processing. I a getting an error below..

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.toSeq. Trace: 
py4j.Py4JException: Method toSeq([class org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path]) does not exist
```

`InputDir = "/Data/Ready/ARRAY_COUNTERS"` # input hdfs directory.

```
hadoop = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop
fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration()
path = hadoop.fs.Path(InputDir)

for f in fs.get(conf).listStatus(path):
    Filename =  f.getPath()

df = spark.read.csv(Filename,header=True)
#I am getting above error in while reading this file.
```

Comment: can you try using as Filename =  str(f.getPath())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About this 2 lines:

```py
    Filename =  f.getPath()

df = spark.read.csv(Filename,header=True)
```

[getPath()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#getPath()) is not a string. Additionally - `f` could be also directory, so to make sure you are not trying to load directory, you can add validation on `f.isFile()`:

```py
if(f.isFile()):
    Filename =  f.getPath()
    df = spark.read.csv(str(Filename),header=True)
```

Now alternative, which worked for me was:

```py
if(f.isFile()):
    Filename =  f.getPath()
    df = sc.textFile(str(Filename), 500).map(lambda x: x.split(", ")) #or any other spearator, returns RDD
    headers=df.first() # to infer schema - you can then convert it to pyspark dataframe with specific column types
```

Comment: when I used str(Filename) I got this error. actually I use this str earlier and it did not solve.pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Can not create a Path from an empty string'

Comment: second option also did not work.. Input path does not exist

Comment: with str(Filename) getting error :pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Can not create a Path from an empty string'

Comment: Try adding ```if(f.isFile()):``` before you start processing Filename. I think you are just processing initial directory, and that's where this error is coming from. (ref: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#isFile())

Comment: also maybe look into globalStatus - you can provide a pattern then (I suppose ```{dir}*.csv``` in your case) ref: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinski...can you also update the answer. along with this. if(f.isFile()):..

Comment: No worries, and @vikrantrana - I added the lines you mentioned